# Looping through 2D array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

If I have a 2D array, how can it be possible to access an entire subarray inside of loop?  Right now I have

```
foreach my $row(@data){  
 foreach my $ind(@$row){  
  #perform operations on specific index  
 }  
}
```

but ideally I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
foreach my $row(@data){  
  #read row data like $row[0], which if it has the data I'm looking for  
  #I can go ahead and access $row[3] while in the same row..
}
```

I'm fairly new to Perl so might just not understand something yet, but I keep "Global symbol "@row" requires explicit package name" when trying to use it the way I want to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close. `$row` is an *array reference* and you access its elements with the deference operator `->[...]`:

```
foreach my $row (@data) {
    if ($row->[0] == 42) { ... }
```

`$row[0]` refers to an element of the array variable `@row`, which is a completely different (and probably undefined -- thus the `Global symbol ...` error message) variable than `$row`.

Answer (score 3):

If `$row` in your code sample is supposed to be a sub-array, or an array reference, you will have to use the indirect notation to access its elements, like `$row->[0]`, `$row->[1]`, etc.

The reason for your error is because `$row[0]` actually implies the existence of an array `@row`, which is probably not present in your script.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this...

```
my @ary = ( [12,13,14,15],
        [57,58,59,60,61,101],
        [67,68,69],
        [77,78,79,80,81,301,302,303]);

for (my $f = 0 ; $f < @ary ; $f++) {
    for (my $s = 0 ; $s < @{$ary[$f]} ; $s++ ) {
        print "$f , $s , $ary[$f][$s]\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: While new answers are always welcome, the answer will be more helpful to others if you also explain *how* the code solves the problem.